# Banach fixed point theorem / convergence squeeze

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to prove a convergence result on an iterative scheme which has the initial point defined as
$$x_1 = \frac{1 - s(x_0)}{s(x_0)}$$
where s(x) is some unknown function.

Here is my theorem and attempted quick sketch of a proof:

For the function $s(x)$ defined as a general polynomial of the form $c_1x^{k_1} + c_2x^{k_2} + ... c_mx^{k_m}$ where $k_1 > k_2 > ... > k_m$ and $x \geq 0$, the convergence time of the algorithm is bounded by that of monic polynomials.

Proof: We proceed by bounding the polynomial cost function. For $0 \leq x < 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
    c_1x^{k_m} < c_1x^{k_1} + c_2x^{k_2} + ... + c_mx^{k_m} < \tilde C x^{k_m}
\end{align*}
where $\tilde C := \sum_i^m c_i$ and identically for $x \geq 1$
\begin{align*}
    c_1x^{k_1} < c_1x^{k_1} + c_2x^{k_2} + ... + c_mx^{k_m} < \tilde C x^{k_1}
\end{align*}
For convenience, let $s_0 := c_1x^{k_1} + c_2x^{k_2} + ... + c_mx^{k_m}$. Using the above bound we demonstrate the following bounds on algorithm for the polynomial
\begin{align*}
    c_1x^{k_m} &< s(x) < \tilde C x^{k_m} \\
    \frac{1}{c_1x^{k_m}} - 1 &> \frac{1}{s(x)} - 1 > \frac{1}{\tilde C x^{k_m}} - 1
\end{align*}
Thus, we have the algorithm bound
\begin{align*}
    x_1(s=c_1x^{k_m}) > x_1(s=s_0) > x_1(s=\tilde C x^{k_m})
\end{align*}
Lastly, manipulating the result from Banach we have
\begin{align*}
    t \geq \ln\left(\frac{(1-L) |x_t - x^*|}{|x_1 - x_0|}\right) / \ln(L)
\end{align*}
and substituting the output of the algorithm for $x_1$ gives us
\begin{align*}
    t \geq \ln\left(\frac{(1-L) |x_t - x^*|}{|x_1(s_0) - x_0|}\right) / \ln(L)
\end{align*}
Denote this bound as $\tau_{s_0}$. Combining the bound with the algorithm bound (tag) gives us
\begin{align*}
    \tau_{c_1x_0^{k_m}} < \tau_{s_0} < \tau_{\tilde C x_0^{k_m}}
\end{align*}
bounding the polynomial function's convergence time with monomials. $\square$

Comment: What do you mean by "convergence time"?

Comment: in this case, the $t$ in the first inequality which is number of iterations for the distance between $x_t - x^*$ to be less than $\epsilon$

Comment: I mean, you might get lucky and have $x_0$ be the fixed point for $g$. Or it could be the fixed point for $C_1x^{k_1}$ or $C_2x^{k_2}$ ...

Comment: added full context and my sketch of proof

Comment: Actually your inequalities hold if all the $c_k$ are positive, which is not any polynomial. Otherwise there is an issue when you go from $a<x<b$ to $\frac1b > \frac1x >\frac1a$. If the all the coefficients are positive it is a strictly increasing function, which is an easier thing to use..but in any case, what is the question?

Comment: So, in the first line of the proof, if $s(x) = x^2 + x$ then you're saying that $x < x^2$ on $[0,1)$?

Comment: (Also, the new version of the question seems very different from the old version.)

Comment: The question was just pertaining to the validity of this proof. I think to resolve the issue of this only holding with positive coefficients I could instead define $\tilde C := \sum |c_i|$. And @NikWeaver no the first line of the proof would give $x < x^2 + x < 2x$ for $x \in (0,1)$

Comment: Did you mean $k_1 < k_2 < \cdots < k_m$ then?

Comment: In this case, $k_1 = 2$ and $k_2 = 1$. I think it is correct as is?

Comment: Oh, I take it back, you're right.